# django file upload

Tags: django, django-admin

I have created a app which will upload the file at a particular location. How can I read the file uploaded after the model is saved? When I click on the file link on `change_field_page` it gives page not found. I'm using Django 1.2 and django-admin for this.

Here's my `models.py`:

```
class UploadClass(models.Model):
  id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  template_name=models.ForeignKey(sas,verbose_name=ugettext_lazy('Template Name'))
  sample=models.FileField(upload_to='%Y/%B/',verbose_name=ugettext_lazy('Sample'))
  status=models.IntegerField(ugettext_lazy('Status'),choices=statusChoices,default=0)
  created_on=models.DateTimeField(ugettext_lazy('Created on'),auto_now_add=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return (self.template_name.name)
```

I'm not doing anything in`forms.py`. How can I open the file after saving the object?

One way to do this is to create a view for the 'url'  and return the file. Are there any others?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the file not being linked correctly from the admin, check your `MEDIA_ROOT` and your `MEDIA_URL` point to, ultimately, the same place. Also, can you give examples of how the `%Y/%B/` is working out as folder names, please? They may not be as you expect.